# BIND is rejecting my key for updating a dns zone

Tags: dns, bind, named

My BIND config has:

```
key "dns-update" {
        algorithm HMAC-SHA512;
        secret "KEYREDACTED==";
};

...

zone "test.org." {
        type master;
        allow-transfer { key "dns-tsig"; };
        allow-update { key "dns-update"; };
        file "/etc/bind/zones/db.test.org";
};
```

Generated my key with:

```
dnssec-keygen -a HMAC-SHA512 -b 512 -n HOST -r /dev/urandom dns-update
```

(Transfers work fine when i configure another host to use dns-tsig)

Updates are not working:

Whether I invoke nsupdate with:

```
nsupdate -y hmac-sha512:dns-update:KEYREDACTED==
```

or

```
nsupdate -k ./Kdns-update.+165+33140.private
```

Once I'm into nsupdate:

```
> server 127.0.0.1
> add some.test.org 60 a 1.1.1.1
> send
update failed: REFUSED
>
```

and in the logs:

```
Jun  1 20:19:34 pentest0 named[30999]: client 127.0.0.1#64585/key dns-update: signer "dns-update" denied
Jun  1 20:19:34 pentest0 named[30999]: client 127.0.0.1#64585/key dns-update: update 'test.org/IN' denied
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you increate logging verbosity to find out if you could have more details?

Answer (score 0):

This is now solved and turned out to be me, bunch of permissions issues - BIND couldn't write to the journal file and, last but not least, typo in my config in the key name (which is not depicted in my example code because I changed the name of it here).